# Problems to create the jar using mvn and springboot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to do a rest server with spring-boot but I'm having some problems with the configuration.

My problem it's that if I try to do mvn install it doesn't generate the jar (it doesn't generate nothing in the target). I don't know if I need to do something specific to generate the jar using spring boot or if I'm doing something bad in the pom.xml. I also tried with mvn clean install, mvn clean package and mvn compile.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>uib.ws.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>WS App Project</name>

    <properties>
        <!-- Data source properties -->
        <dataSource.user>uibRT</dataSource.user>
        <dataSource.password>uibRT</dataSource.password>
        <dataSource.jndiName>jdbc/AppRecipe</dataSource.jndiName>
        <testDataSource.user>${dataSource.user}</testDataSource.user>
        <testDataSource.password>${dataSource.password}</testDataSource.password>

        <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <hibernate.show_sql>true</hibernate.show_sql>
        <hibernate.format_sql>true</hibernate.format_sql>
        <hibernate.use_sql_comments>true</hibernate.use_sql_comments>

        <!-- Encoding -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Package versions -->
        <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
        <javassist.version>3.21.0-GA</javassist.version>
        <cglib.version>3.2.3</cglib.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.7.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <springboot.version>1.5.8.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <jayway.version>2.0.0</jayway.version>
        <commonsDbcp.version>2.1.1</commonsDbcp.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <servletApi.version>2.3</servletApi.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.2</httpclient.version>
        <jdom2.version>2.0.6</jdom2.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- JDBC driver properties -->
        <jdbcDriver.groupId>org.postgresql</jdbcDriver.groupId>
        <jdbcDriver.artifactId>postgresql</jdbcDriver.artifactId>
        <jdbcDriver.version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</jdbcDriver.version>
        <jdbcDriver.className>org.postgresql.Driver</jdbcDriver.className>

        <!-- Data source properties -->
        <dataSource.baseUrl>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/AppRecipe</dataSource.baseUrl>
        <dataSource.url>${dataSource.baseUrl}?useSSL=false</dataSource.url>
        <testDataSource.url>${dataSource.baseUrl}Test</testDataSource.url>
        <dataSource.createTablesScript>1-CreateTables.sql</dataSource.createTablesScript>
        <dataSource.createDataScript>2-CreateData.sql</dataSource.createDataScript>

        <!-- Plugin versions -->
        <mavenCompilerPlugin.version>3.5.1</mavenCompilerPlugin.version>
        <mavenResourcesPlugin.version>3.0.1</mavenResourcesPlugin.version>
        <sqlMavenPlugin.version>1.5</sqlMavenPlugin.version>
        <mavenAssemblyPlugin.version>2.6</mavenAssemblyPlugin.version>
        <pojo-modelutil.version>2.3.1</pojo-modelutil.version>     
        <jettyMavenPlugin>9.3.10.v20160621</jettyMavenPlugin>

    </properties>

    <!-- ========================================================== -->
    <!-- Profiles -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>win</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <tool.wsgen>${java.home}/../bin/wsgen.exe</tool.wsgen>
                <tool.wsimport>${java.home}/../bin/wsimport.exe</tool.wsimport>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>nix</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>!windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <tool.wsgen>${java.home}/../bin/wsgen</tool.wsgen>
                <tool.wsimport>${java.home}/../bin/wsimport</tool.wsimport>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>postgresql</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- JDBC driver properties -->
                <jdbcDriver.groupId>${jdbcDriver.groupId}</jdbcDriver.groupId>
                <jdbcDriver.artifactId>${jdbcDriver.artifactId}</jdbcDriver.artifactId>
                <jdbcDriver.version>${jdbcDriver.version}</jdbcDriver.version>
                <jdbcDriver.className>${jdbcDriver.className}</jdbcDriver.className>

                <!--  Data source properties -->
                <dataSource.baseUrl>${dataSource.baseUrl}</dataSource.baseUrl>
                <dataSource.url>${dataSource.url}</dataSource.url>
                <testDataSource.url>${testDataSource.url}</testDataSource.url>
                <dataSource.createTablesScript>${dataSource.createTablesScript}</dataSource.createTablesScript>
                <dataSource.createDataScript>${dataSource.createDataScript}</dataSource.createDataScript>

                <!-- Hibernate properties -->
                <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQlDialect</hibernate.dialect>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JDBC driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${jdbcDriver.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${jdbcDriver.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbcDriver.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Commons DBCP - JDBC Connection Pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${commonsDbcp.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SLF4J (required by Hibernate) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Javassist (required by Hibernate) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CGLIB (required by Spring) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SpringBoot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- =============================================================== -->
        <!-- Filtering -->
        <resources>

            <!-- Apply filtering to files matching the following expressions 
                in src/main/resources. -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>spring-config.xml</include> 
                    <include>hibernate-config.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <!-- Continue considering resources the files in src/main/resources, 
                but without applying filtering. -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>

        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <!-- Continue considering resources the files in src/test/resources, 
                but without applying filtering. -->
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>

        </testResources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
            <!-- 
                 Added to avoid problems with the maven plugin for 
                 eclipse
            -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>${sqlMavenPlugin.version}</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>execute</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ========================================================== -->
            <!-- Compiler configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mavenCompilerPlugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ========================================================== -->
            <!-- Resources plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mavenResourcesPlugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ========================================================== -->
            <!-- Exec plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ========================================================== -->
            <!-- Setting SQL Plugin -->
            <!-- - Configuration specifies onError="continue" since SQL scripts 
                try to drop tables before creating them (which causes errors if such tables 
                do not exist yet). - Configuartion specifies autocommit="true" since some 
                drivers (e.g the PostgreSQL JDBC 2 driver) do not commit changes if some 
                error ocurrs. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sqlMavenPlugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>${jdbcDriver.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${jdbcDriver.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${jdbcDriver.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <driver>${jdbcDriver.className}</driver>
                    <url>${dataSource.url}</url>
                    <username>${dataSource.user}</username>
                    <password>${dataSource.password}</password>
                    <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                    <onError>continue</onError>
                    <orderFile>ascending</orderFile> 
                    <fileset>
                        <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                        <includes>
                            <include>src/sql/${dataSource.createTablesScript}</include>
                            <include>src/sql/${dataSource.createDataScript}</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-tables-for-testing</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <driver>${jdbcDriver.className}</driver>
                            <url>${testDataSource.url}</url>
                            <username>${testDataSource.user}</username>
                            <password>${testDataSource.password}</password>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <onError>continue</onError>
                            <fileset>
                                <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>
                                        src/sql/${dataSource.createTablesScript}
                                    </include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileset>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ========================================================== -->
            <!-- Assembly configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mavenAssemblyPlugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ========================================================== -->
            <!-- Jetty configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jettyMavenPlugin}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <port>9090</port>
                    </httpConnector>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
                        <jettyEnvXml>target/jetty/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <reload>manual</reload>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>${jdbcDriver.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${jdbcDriver.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${jdbcDriver.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.version}</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ========================================================== -->
            <!-- Springboot plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And here is my src.xml in the assembly folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<assembly>
    <id>src</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
        <format>tar.bz2</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/.project</exclude>
                <exclude>**/.classpath</exclude>
                <exclude>**/.settings/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/target/**</exclude>
                <exclude>**/META-INF/**</exclude> <!-- Created by m2eclipse -->
                <exclude>.git/**</exclude>
                <exclude>.gitignore</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Here is the structure of my project: [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z55rD.png)

Comment: You should also use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and for starting use the spring boot parent....I don't know why you are using maven-assembly-plugin etc.

Comment: OP has both... I guess spring-boot-maven-plugin overrides it

Comment: It's my first time working with spring boot and I don't really know what configuration I need. Should I delete the assembly configuration?

Comment: Yes, cause you don't need it...

Comment: And also remove your src.xml, because you don't need that either. Oh and while we're at it,  remove all properties in your postgres profile, except the last. You can also remove your `<resources>` and `<testResources>`, that is the default. Maybe your pluginManagement, you're using it nowhere. You are also defining a couple of the plugins which are defaults, search which are default and remove them. Finally, you aren't using anything from spring's Maven repository, so press delete on that. Everything should still be the same after doing all this.

Comment: Thank you so much. The pluginManagement it's used to create the tables for the test, but deleting the other stuff it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring Boot you can create runnable jars which you can run via cmd.

The problem is you aren't telling Maven to create a jar!
Would you try changing your packaging inside your pom from `pom` to `jar`, like so:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

EDIT:
If your pom is missing a `<packaging>` tag, maven's default is `jar`.

Comment: Or just simply omit the packaging completely which results in using the default which is `jar`.

Comment: OP seems to enjoy writing everything out in his pom ;) but your right.